# background service for Notification is not working

Tags: android, android-service

I tried to use the following code trigger toast as background service but it gets **executed for 20 times,** it was not working till 100. With thread it is not working gives error.

> Felt service get destroyed.

- How to trigger notification with 30 minutes difference as a background service, though app is closed,
- I need to display Good morning, Good Afternoon, Good Evening and Good night as a Notification.
- without any internet support.

Is following procedure not ok? I think so. How to do this?

```
import android.app.Service;

public class HelloService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "HelloService";
    int i=0;
    private boolean isRunning  = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
        Toast.makeText(this, " On create Hello Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");



                for (;i<100; i++) {
                    try {
//                     Thread.sleep(1000);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello Service On Loop"+i , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }

                //Stop service once it finishes its task
//        i++;
                stopSelf();


        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        isRunning = false;

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
    }
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

`onStartCommand()` is called on the main (UI) thread. If you execute a loop inside `onStartCommand()`, Android will kill the process after about 30 seconds with an ANR (Application Not Responding) because you cannot block the main (UI) thread.

You can do what you want either using `AlarmManager` to set a timer that will start your `Service` or trigger a `BroadcastReceiver` at certain times, or you can post a `Runnable` to a `Handler` in `onStartCommand()` with a certain delay and do whatever you want in the `Runnable`, or you can start a background thread in `onStartCommand()` and the background thread can loop and sleep or whatever and then do what you want.

In any case, you cannot show a `Toast` every second. This will flood the UI with toasts and either Android will dump most of them (ignore them) or the UI will be so busy showing them that Android will kill your app due to ANR or the user will just uninstall your app!